# why is my jqGrid is empty eventhough json data is present

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Here is my jqGrid, that is not displaying any data.

[image: No Grid Data]

I'm getting the json response for the grid, but it is not displaying.

Here is what i've done so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;

        function getCompanyData() {
        //debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "jqGrid_pureJS.aspx/GetCompanyList",
                data: "{}",  // "{}" For empty input data use "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    //debugger;
                    var grdData = $("#jqGrid")[0];
                    grdData.addJSONData(result.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    //debugger;
                }
            });
        }
        $(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: getCompanyData,
                colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Address', 'City', 'Phone'],
                colModel: [
                          { name: 'F1', index: 'invid', width: 55 },
                          { name: 'F2', index: 'invdate', width: 90,editable:true },
                          { name: 'F3', index: 'amount', width: 80,editable:true, align: 'right' },
                          { name: 'F4', index: 'tax', width: 80,editable:true, align: 'right' },
                          { name: 'F5', index: 'total', width: 80,editable:true, align: 'right' }
                ],
                pager: $("#pager"),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'My first grid',
                width:800

            }).navGrid('#pager', { edit:true,view: true, del: false });
        });

    </script>
```

And here is my webmethod that posts data.

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json,UseHttpGet=false)]
        public static string GetCompanyList()
        {

            var data = GetAllData();
            try
            {
                string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

And here is my json responce captured:

```
    {"d":"
    [\r\n  
        {\r\n    
        \"F1\": 1.0,\r\n    
        \"F2\": \"Name\",\r\n    
        \"F3\": \"Address\",\r\n    
        \"F4\": \"City\",\r\n    
        \"F5\": \"Phone\"\r\n  
        },
        \r\n  
        {\r\n    
        \"F1\": 10.0,\r\n    
        \"F2\": \"abc\",\r\n    
        \"F3\": \"def\",\r\n    
        \"F4\": \"asd\",\r\n    
        \"F5\": \"998907\"\r\n  
        }
    ]
}
```

I could see similar question [jqgrid not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246607/jqgrid-not-showing-rows-only-shows-total-number-of-rows), i've checked it and i did not get rid of my problem though

Why is the json data not appended ? How do i do it ?

**Edit**

as part of the answer, i've removed my javascript to call the jqGrid and replaced the code for it as posted in the answer by oleg.

Also i've made little changes to the code in the server side.

Here is what the server side code is:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
        public static string GetCompanyList()
        {
            var data = GetAllData();

            //string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
            return data;

        }

        public static string GetAllData()
        {
            try
            {
                //Grab the connection string defined in web.config
                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test_3ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                DataTable dt = null;

                //Command Text
                string commandText = "SELECT * FROM EmpDetails";

                dt = SQLHelper.ExecuteDataTable(connectionString, CommandType.Text, commandText, "EmpDetails");

                string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Things going weird hour by hour. When i run my application i've the following grid.

[image: weird issue]

I only have `9 rows in my table` and it is displaying `viewing 1-10 of 552`.

Can someone please help me what is wrong with the serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are may errors in your code. It looks like you used some retro code example which is at least 3 years old.

The main error in the server code is usage of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` inside of web method. If you defines `ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json` then the method should return **object** of any type and not `string`. .Net convert the object **automatically** to JSON. So the type of return value of `GetCompanyList()` should be the same as the return type of `GetAllData()`. After the changes the web method should returns the data like

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "F1": 1,
            "F2": "Name",
            "F3": "Address",
            "F4": "City",
            "F5": "Phone"
        },
        {
            "F1": 10,
            "F2": "abc",
            "F3": "def",
            "F4": "asd",
            "F5": "998907"
        }
    ]
}
```

The second problem that you use `datatype` defined as function. It's low-level way which you should *never use* if you can get the data with respect `jQuery.ajax` with some parameters. jqGrid provide a lot of different customization way to change parameters of `jQuery.ajax` used by jqGrid internally. Typically it's enough to specify the options like

```
url: "jqGrid_pureJS.aspx/GetCompanyList",
mtype: 'POST',
datatype: 'json',
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
},
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
},
gridview: true,
height: "auto",
loadonce: true
```

It's important additionally to remove all `index` properties from `colModel`. The usage of `index` other as `name` follows to errors if you use `loadonce: true` option.

If `F1` column contains *unique* values then I recommend you to add `key: true` property to the definition of the column `"F1"`.

The results of the changes should be like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/karthik.htm):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like problem at the server side i'm unable to get the problem resolved yet. I've used your script code which is correct. I've also changed the return types of both the methods in server side to `DataTable` but it doesnot get me started. If you have any links for the calling WebMethods from jqGrid please post them

Comment: @karthik: You have still `string GetCompanyList()` signature. It should not return `string` type. The returned JSON data should be like I posted. So `GetCompanyList` should return array/list of items which are objects having properties/fields `F1`, `F2`, ..., `F5`

Comment: Thank you oleg. Finally i've sorted out the problem.

Comment: I could see lots of stuff using php with jqGrid but i couldn't find anything for asp.net even on [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid) for opensource javascript. if you know any tutorials or get started with jqgrid for asp.net can you please post a link if you are free

Comment: @karthik: I don't use PHP myself and use only different variants of ASP.NET. I posted many code examples in the past. In general jqGrid makes just `jQuery.ajax` call to the URL which you provide. If you examine HTTP traffic with Fiddler or Firebug it will be mostly wnat you need. You can download VS projects from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935)), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4031603/315935), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3918615/315935) and many other.

Comment: Thank you !! you are very helpful to all the posts with tag `jqGrid`